# Change site template from php

Tags: templates, switch-theme

What is the argument to pass to switch theme, when I have the result of `wp_get_themes()`?

```
 $args = array(
        'allowed' => true
 );

 $themes = wp_get_themes(  );

 foreach ($themes as $theme) {

          $argument_to_pass_to_switch_theme = ??????

 }
```

Comment: Why are you switching themes in a Loop? What is the use case for this?

Comment: I'm not, I just need the variable to echo it later...

Comment: For temporary preview/theme switch (while visitor still see the default theme), then you can use plugins: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161196/42702

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you should use this inside your `foreach`:

```
$argument_to_pass_to_switch_theme = $theme->get_stylesheet();
```

---

Just taking a look at the documentation:

The function [`wp_get_themes()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_themes)...

> *"...returns an array of WP_Theme objects based on the argument."*

This class [`WP_Theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Theme) has a method [`get_stylesheet()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Theme#Path_and_URL_Methods), which...

> *"...returns a string with the directory name of the theme's "stylesheet" files, inside the theme root. If this is a child theme it is the directory from the child theme. "*

And the function [`switch_theme()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme)...

> *"...accepts one argument: $stylesheet of the theme. ($stylesheet is the name of your folder slug."*

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_get_themes()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_themes) returns a [`WP_Theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Theme) object, one of the methods of which, `get_stylesheet()` will return the value you need to pass to `switch_theme()`

You are not likely to get "the variable" to `echo` later. If you have more than one theme and is nearly always the case (as you should keep a bundled theme just in case) you are going to have multiple variables, so you need to create an array and not a string.

```
$themes = wp_get_themes();
foreach ($themes as $theme) {
  $argument_to_pass_to_switch_theme[] =  $theme->get_stylesheet();
}

var_dump($argument_to_pass_to_switch_theme);
```

If you run the code as you have it mocked up...

```
$themes = wp_get_themes();
foreach ($themes as $theme) {
  $argument_to_pass_to_switch_theme =  $theme->get_stylesheet();
}

var_dump($argument_to_pass_to_switch_theme);
```

... you will overwrite the `$argument_to_pass_to_switch_theme` variable at every iteration of the loop and only end up with the stylesheet name for the last theme in the loop.